# How to configure ASP.NET Core to handle circular references without breaking the body's response?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public Example Demo()
    {
        return new Example("test");
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public Example(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; }

        public IEnumerable<Example> Demos
        {
            get { yield return this; }
        }
    }
}
```

When querying `/api/SampleData/Demo`, I get as response body:

```
{"name":"test","demos":[
```

...which is obviously very broken JSON-like output.

How and where do I have to configure my ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC-based app to make the framework serialize circular references in a way that does not break the output? (For example, by introducing `$ref` and `$id`.)

Comment: Try `return Ok(new Example("test"));`. For circular dependencies in ORM I would use automapper to map it to a viewmodel, creating explicit rules for how to deal with the circular references in the automapper profile, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate in this case. I suspect it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to switch on references for JSON.Net serialization, you should set `PreserveReferencesHandling` property of `SerializerSettings` to `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` enum value.

In ASP.Net Core you could do it by following adjustment in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    });
```

Now the model will be serialized to following correct JSON:

```
{
  "$id": "2",
  "name": "test",
  "demos": [ { "$ref": "2" } ]
}
```