# How to make lazy-loading work with EF Core 2.1.0 and proxies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following models:

```
public class Session
{
    public int SessionID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}

public class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

that are registered in `DbContext` as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Session>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("sessions");

    entity.Property(e => e.SessionID).HasColumnName("id");
    entity.Property(e => e.UserID).HasColumnName("user_id");

    entity.HasOne(e => e.User)
        .WithMany(e => e.Sessions)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserID);
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("users");

    entity.Property(e => e.UserID).HasColumnName("id");
    entity.Property(e => e.OrganizationID).HasColumnName("organization_id");

    entity.HasOne(e => e.Organization)
        .WithMany(e => e.Users)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrganizationID);
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("organizations");

    entity.Property(e => e.OrganizationID).HasColumnName("id");
}
```

I'm trying to use lazy loading with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading):

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();
    optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        /* more options */
        ;

    var opts = optionsBuilder.Options;

    return new Context(opts);
}).As<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I'm querying sessions using `context.All<Session>`. However, `Session.User` and `Session.User.Organization` are null by default. To load them I have to do something like `context.All<Session>().Include(s => s.User).Include(s => s.User.Organization)`. How can I avoid that? Why doesn't `UseLazyLoadingProxies` work?

---

- .NET Core version: `2.1.300-preview2-008533`
- Target: `netcoreapp2.1`
- EF Core (and Proxies) version: `2.1.0-preview2-final`

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution? Having the same issue

Comment: To be honest, do you really need lazy-loading? I tried that with full EF and found it not very usefull, since it only works as long as you have your context alive,so if you want to just fetch all information, you still have to manually load all properties or keep the context alive. I created extension methods for DbSets like BuildSession, BuldUser that contain all includes I need.

Answer (score 20):

**Steps To Configure Lazy Loading with Proxies in Asp.net Core 2.1**

1. Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package
2. Enable LazyLoadingProxies
   You can enable it with a call to UseLazyLoadingProxies:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

Or when using AddDbContext:

```
.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
      .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

3. EF Core will then enable lazy loading for any navigation property that can be overridden--that is, it must be virtual.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to configure proxies in `Startup.cs` like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    #region Database configuration

    // Database configuration
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));

    #endregion Database configuration
}
```

And by the way you can already update you app packages to pure 2.1.0 (not final or RC). One of the reasons why your configuration may not work is an unstable version of components.

NB: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies.dll` is installed from nuget independently from EFCore

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting JSON serialization in service like this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350457/4178475