# Getting related entities to an ASP.NET Identity User

Tags: asp.net

Using asp.net Identity, I'm trying to work out if my AppUser has any Businesses attached (using a one to many relationship)

In the database I have an AppUser with many Businesses connected, but when I run the query to retrieve my user, Businesses is always null.

If I manually call the AspNetUsers table via a context and Include() the Businesses then they show up ok, but I thought the virtual keyword would retrieve the properties regardless?

Here is my user class:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser() {
        Businesses = new List<Business>();
    }

    public bool HasABusinessProfile
    {
        get
        {
            return Businesses.Any();
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
}
```

On login:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]UserLoginViewModel credentials)
{
    var user = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);
```

The problem is that at this point in the code, user.HasABusinessProfile is always false.

Comment: what is the EF version that you used?

Comment: Im using ef core 2.1

Comment: wah, i assume you are having null on `HasABusinessProfile` method? because if i remember correctly EF Core dont have lazy loading on by default yet. so you might need to call `Include` before using the relation. to turn it on, you could check on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50718445/4648586) or read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading). not sure how to do that on membership though, need to find the context declaration or at least extend it.