# Entity Framework Core - lazy loading doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, asp.net-core-2.0, eager-loading

Given the following 3 (simplified) classes:

- ClassA { int Id; }
- ClassB { int Id; }
- JunctionClass { ClassA classA; ClassB classB; }

When I am trying to load the `JunctionClass` list...

```
var junctionClassList = _appDbContext.JunctionClass
                                     .Include(jc => jc.ClassA)
                                     .Include(jc => jc.ClassB).ToList();
```

the code doesn't load the `ClassA` and `ClassB` objects.

I have found a fix, but I don't think that I'm using EF Core the way it should be used:

```
var classAList = _appDbContext.ClassA.ToList();
var classBList = _appDbContext.ClassB.ToList();

var junctionClassList = _appDbContext.JunctionClass
                                     .Include(jc => jc.ClassA)
                                     .Include(jc => jc.ClassB).ToList();
```

This way, the `junctionClassList` object will also load the `classA` and `classB` dependencies.

My question is this - is this the correct way to use lazy/eager loading? Or is there another way?

Comment: did you add virtual keyword for ClassA and ClassB in JunctionClass?

Comment: I did, but still no results. However, I did not update the database after adding the "virtual" keyword. Should I?

Comment: Which EF  Core version u have ?

Comment: 2.1.3-rtm-32065

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180326/how-to-make-lazy-loading-work-with-ef-core-2-1-0-and-proxies

Comment: Share us the complete defination for `ClassA` and `JunctionClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Eager loading in this case using `Include`. [Lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) is introduced in EF Core 2.1. You need to enable it explicitly.

Comment: If I'm using Eager loading right now, shouldn't the classA and classB objects be loaded anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Below defination works for `Include`.

```
    public class JunctionClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassB ClassB { get; set; }

}
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Share us the difference from yours.